# Does electrically neutral mean the potential is zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, voltage

I don't know if this is a silly question, but I have a homework problem that tells me a line charge is electrically neutral at time $t=0$.  I was calculating the potential from the definition
$$ V(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\int\frac{1}{\mathcal{r}}\rho(\boldsymbol{r}')d\tau', $$
and then I began to worry that I am supposed to assume the potential is zero since the object is electrically neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Electrically neutral means the net charge is zero. There might be no charge present at that location, or there might be an equal density of positive and negative charge.

The potential at that point might be 0 or it might be non-zero due to the effect of charge at other locations.

For example if you have a point charge in space, the potential at a point `A` few cm away from that charge is not zero even though there is no charge at point `A`.

Comment: This is all assuming a set location where $V=0$ of course

Comment: @BioPhysicist, Or assuming V = 0 "at infinity".

Comment: Ok great!  Thank you for your help!